# Get checkbox values in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

i'am working on checkboxes when user click checkbox i am checking is it checked or not if checked i update value on database here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() 
    {
         var tObj = $(this).val();
         if ($('#checkpermission').is(':checked'))
         {
            alert(tObj);
            $.ajax({
                  url: 'checkpermission.php',
                  data: {"Selected":tObj},
                  type: 'post',
                  success:function(data)
                  {
                     alert(data);
                     //Succes!
                  }
            });
         }
         else
         {
             // alert(tObj);
             $.ajax({
                   url: 'uncheckpermission.php',
                   data: {"Selected":tObj},
                   type: 'post',
                   success:function(data)
                   {
                      alert(data);
                      //Succes!
                   }
             });
         }
    });

});


   <?php
session_start();
require 'dbconnect.php';
$page_name="RegisterUsers.php";
$start=$_GET['start'];
if(strlen($start) > 0 and !is_numeric($start))
{
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}
$eu = ($start - 0);
$limit = 8;
$this1 = $eu + $limit;
$back = $eu - $limit;
$next = $eu + $limit;



$query="select * from tbl_user where username!='admin' and password!='admin'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$nume=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($nume>0)
{


if($_REQUEST['SearchText'])
{

$find=$_REQUEST['SearchText'];
$query="select * from tbl_user where username!='admin' and password!='admin' and username LIKE'%$find%' or Email LIKE'%$find%' or PhoneNumber LIKE'%$find%' order by id limit  $eu, $limit";
}
else
{
$query="select * from tbl_user where username!='admin' and password!='admin' order by username limit  $eu, $limit";
}
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
 if($data[5])
 {
 $path=$redirect."/services/User/".$data[5];
 }
 else
 {
 $path=$redirect."/images/noimage.png";
 }
?>
 <tr>
<td class="gallery">

<a href='<?=$path ?>'>
 <img width="50" height="50" src=<?php echo $path; ?> />
 </a>

</td>
<!--<td id='myText'><img width=50 height=50 src=<?php echo $path; ?> /></a></td>-->
 <td><?=$data[1]?></td> 
 <td><?=$data[3]?></td>
 <td><?=$data[4]?></td>
 <td>
 <div style="padding-left:25px;">
 <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" class="checkpermission" name="checkuser" id="checkpermission" value='<?=$data[0]?>'<?php if($data[6]=="Read-Write"){echo "checked";}?>>
 </div>
 <div>
 Read-Write
 </div>
 </td>

<td class='delete'><a  href='http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/AddUser.php?id=<?=$data[0]?>&action=edit' >Edit</a></td>
 <td class='delete'><a href='http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/RegisterUsers.php?id=<?=$data[0]?>&action=delete' onClick="return deletepressed();">Delete</a></td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

every time when user click goes on if condition only else loop not working i am seeing response

so can any one guide me how can i overcome this
Thanks for advance.

Comment: what error you are getting with this code.

Comment: every time $('#checkpermission').bind('click', function() { alert($("#checkpermission").is(':checked'));//true every time });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
if($("#checkpermission:checked").length > 0)
```

**Solution**

There were more than one check box with `checkpermission`. So the code needs to be modified like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() 
{
     var tObj = $(this).val();
     if ($(this).is(':checked'))
     {
         //Rest of the code
```

Ajay will change the code to generate unique ids for the checkbox. Above code will work for this case too.

Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9sLY/6/)

Hope this works for you.

Comment: What are you doing inside `onchange`? Can you bind `change` event using jQuery? Check this http://jsfiddle.net/G9sLY/5/

Comment: every time $('#checkpermission').bind('click', function() {
   
    alert($("#checkpermission").is(':checked'));//true every time
});

Comment: Where did you test it? In your project or on jsFiddle. Also let me know which browser you are using? Is it happening on browsers?

Comment: i am testing on project i am using chrome

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer but can you remove `value='<?=$data[0]?>'<?php if($data[6]=="Read-Write"){echo "checked";}?>` this and try? What is this code doing? It might be setting `checked` always.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7407/discussion-between-ajay-chthri-and-amar-palsapure)

Answer (score 1):

`$('input:checkbox:checked').val()` should work :)

Comment: every time i click check box it goes if ($('#checkpermission').is(':checked'))
     {
       alert(tObj);
       $.ajax({
       url: 'checkpermission.php',
       data: {"Selected":tObj},
       type: 'post',
       success:function(data)
       {
         alert(data);
           //Succes!
       }
    });

Comment: @AjayChthri else condition will only work when you uncheck the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

As you are putting "if condition" after click happen so your "else condition" will work only when you uncheck the checkbox.

check this example: i have putted one alert in else condition.

http://jsfiddle.net/yHZsG/